# Copy row to another worksheet when conditions are met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like a row in sheet1 (`main`) to be copied from column A to K when a certain condition is entered in cell L of  that row, If column L contains 'up' is should be copied to the next available row sheet2 (`Sub`). if column L on sheet1 (`Main`) is changed from 'up' to 'down' then should be removed from Sheet2 (`Sub`) and copied to Sheet3 (`Done`) and vice versa.

```
function copyrange() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Main'); //source sheet
    var testrange = sheet.getRange('L:L');
    var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
    var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Sub'); //destination sheet
    var sch = ss.getSheetByName('Done'); //destination sheet
    var data = [];
    var j =[];


    //Condition check in L:L; If true copy the same row to data array
    for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if ( testvalue[i] === 'up') // changed to ===, == is used to check if they are the same object(have same memory location).
    {
        data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,11).getValues());

        // Copy matched ROW numbers to j
        j.push(i);
        csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length)
           .setValues(data);
    }
    else ( testvalue[i] === 'down') // changed to ===, ditto.
    {
        data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,11).getValues());

        //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
        j.push(i);
        sch.getRange(sch.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length)
           .setValues(data);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! There are countless examples of code similar to what your title describes; take some time to search existing answers. Also check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and see "[ask]", as well as the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Comment: Well, what's the issue? You just ask for help, which isn't really a specific programming question that has a useful answer. (PS: the comments about `===` and `==` should be rewritten after reviewing JavaScript comparison operators.)

Comment: @HishamAl-Amoudi It would be helpful if you shared your spreadsheet so we can see the data. I'm intrigued to see how the row numbers work, as this is the key to know which row is to be deleted in Sheet B. The code you supplied doesn't really explain where or why you are having a problem.